# How to navigate without without typing "cd foldername" all the time?

Tags: command-line, navigation

I am new to this whole thing and I was wondering if there is an easier way to travel between folders, like I just type one thing and I get to see what folders and I can go into and then I press one button and I'm in them, cause that seems more convenient and easier.

Comment: One possible solution would be to use command line file browser like `nnn` (yes, that's it name) - check more here `https://github.com/jarun/nnn`. You can easily navigate the file tree with it just by typing and using arrow keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In text mode (and terminal windows) you can use Midnight Commander, `mc`, where you can navigate with the arrow keys and enter key (highlight a directory and press Enter to enter into it).

The program `mc` is available via the package 'mc' in the repository 'universe'.

```
sudo apt install mc
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you work in the terminal or in the console, `cd` is the way to navigate, and `ls` will list files and directories available in your current working directory.

If you want a more graphical approach, you can use the file-manager (Nautilus) where you can click around the file-system.

Comment: And in Nautilus once you found your place you can right-click "Open in terminal"